# How to convert html with images to word using win32com in python

Tags: python, html, ms-word

I am using win32com to convert html to word in python (Django).

Am facing issues with images part i.e. the html page contains images which are not coming in the final word doc.

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')

doc = word.Documents.Add('example.html')
doc.SaveAs('example.doc', FileFormat=0)
doc.Close()

word.Quit()
```

This is the code am using. What can be done about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this appears to be a shortcoming of Word. Refer to [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2004/Apr/13/Image-Problems-when-Importing-HTML-into-Microsoft-Word-via-Automation) for more information.

The 'simplest' solution is to open the html document, select all, copy and then paste into a new document. This will embed the images.

```
import os
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

in_file  = os.path.abspath("example.html")
in_name  = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(in_file)[1])[0]
out_file = os.path.abspath("%s.doc" % in_name)

# Open and copy HTML
doc = word.Documents.Add(in_file)
word.Selection.WholeStory()
word.Selection.Copy()
doc.Close()

# Open new document, paste HTML and save
doc = word.Documents.Add()
word.Selection.Paste()
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=0)
doc.Close()

word.Quit()
```

Comment: Didn't work for me - the images don't appear